# XML visual basic 6

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, vb6

I am trying to read in an XML file into our VB6 app. I have gone through lots of code trying to get the "modifiers" for each "item" in the list, but can only retrieve them all at the same time. The problem seems to be they are all named the same! Any help would be greatly appreciated! - KC

Here is the XML :

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <GetNewOrdersResponse>
        <ResultCode>0</ResultCode>
        <Message>Ok</Message>
        <LocationID>436</LocationID>
        <StoreTimeGMT>2015-11-27 05:13:38</StoreTimeGMT>
        <TotalRecords>1</TotalRecords>
        <Tickets>
            <ticket>
        <order_id>5278</order_id>
        <type>TAKEOUT</type>
        <comments></comments>
        <customer>
            <customer_id></customer_id>
            <phone_id></phone_id>
            <firstname>Kyle</firstname>
            <lastname>Cross</lastname>
            <email>crosskg62@gmail.com</email>
            <phone>4438786137</phone>
        </customer>
        <created_timestamp>2015-11-26 23:19:47</created_timestamp>
        <requested_timestamp>2015-11-27 17:00:00</requested_timestamp>
        <items>
            <item id="21845" pos_id="5702">
                <name>Cheese Pizza</name>
                <size>12"</size>
                <quantity>1</quantity>
                <price>8.95</price>
                <comments></comments>
                <modifiers>
                    <modifier id="44347" pos_id="3252">
                        <name>Thick</name>
                        <price>0.00</price>
                        <quantity>1</quantity>
                    </modifier>
                    <modifier id="44349" pos_id="6000">
                        <name>Cheddar Cheese</name>
                        <price>0.00</price>
                        <quantity>whole_extra</quantity>
                    </modifier>
                    <modifier id="44350" pos_id="6003">
                        <name>Green Olives</name>
                        <price>0.50</price>
                        <quantity>left</quantity>
                    </modifier>
                    <modifier id="44351" pos_id="6005">
                        <name>Black Olives</name>
                        <price>0.50</price>
                        <quantity>right</quantity>
                    </modifier>
                    <modifier id="44353" pos_id="6009">
                        <name>Tomatoes</name>
                        <price>1.00</price>
                        <quantity>whole</quantity>
                    </modifier>
                    <modifier id="44355" pos_id="6013">
                        <name>Pineapple</name>
                        <price>0.50</price>
                        <quantity>right</quantity>
                    </modifier>
                </modifiers>
            </item>
            <item id="21782" pos_id="5001">
                <name>Big Burger</name>
                <size></size>
                <quantity>3</quantity>
                <price>8.95</price>
                <comments></comments>
                <modifiers>
                    <modifier id="44287" pos_id="3044">
                        <name>Well</name>
                        <price>0.00</price>
                        <quantity>1</quantity>
                    </modifier>
                    <modifier id="44306" pos_id="5100">
                        <name>Cole Slaw</name>
                        <price>0.00</price>
                        <quantity>1</quantity>
                    </modifier>
                </modifiers>
            </item>
            <item id="21805" pos_id="4700">
                <name>Fried Chicken Salad</name>
                <size></size>
                <quantity>1</quantity>
                <price>10.95</price>
                <comments></comments>
                <modifiers>
                    <modifier id="44318" pos_id="3030">
                        <name>Blue Cheese</name>
                        <price>0.00</price>
                        <quantity>1</quantity>
                    </modifier>
                </modifiers>
            </item>
        </items>
        <subtotal>49.25</subtotal>
        <tax>3.45</tax>
        <total>52.70</total>
        <PaymentType>CASH</PaymentType>
        <PaymentStatus>UNPAID</PaymentStatus>
    </ticket>
</Tickets>
```

Here is the code:

```
    Dim xmlDoc As DOMDocument
    Dim objNodeList As IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim objNodeList2 As IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim objProductNode As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim objQuantityNode As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim objNode As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim objNode2 As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim XMLurl As String
```

Dim strRet As String

```
Set xmlDoc = New DOMDocument
XMLurl = "c:\kyle.xml"

xmlDoc.async = False

If xmlDoc.Load(XMLurl) = False Then
    MsgBox ("XML LOAD ERROR")
Else
    i = 0
    Set objNodeList = xmlDoc.selectNodes("//items")
    For Each objNode In objNodeList

        mPrice = objNode.selectSingleNode("//price").Text
        mPrice = objNode.selectSingleNode("//price").Text
        mQty = objNode.selectSingleNode("//quantity").Text
        mQty = objNode.selectSingleNode("//size").Text

    Next 'objNode

    ' get the modifiers for that node
    Set objNodeList2 = xmlDoc.selectNodes("//Modifier")
    For Each objNode2 In objNodeList2

        mName = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//name").Text
        mPrice = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//price").Text
        mQty = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//quantity").Text

    Next objNode2
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Use relative path expressions once you have selected a node, that is, change

```
Set objNodeList = xmlDoc.selectNodes("//items")
For Each objNode In objNodeList

    mPrice = objNode.selectSingleNode("//price").Text
    mPrice = objNode.selectSingleNode("//price").Text
    mQty = objNode.selectSingleNode("//quantity").Text
    mQty = objNode.selectSingleNode("//size").Text

Next 'objNode

' get the modifiers for that node
Set objNodeList2 = xmlDoc.selectNodes("//Modifier")
For Each objNode2 In objNodeList2

    mName = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//name").Text
    mPrice = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//price").Text
    mQty = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//quantity").Text

Next objNode2
```

to

```
Set objNodeList = xmlDoc.selectNodes("//item")
For Each objNode In objNodeList

    mPrice = objNode.selectSingleNode("price").Text

    mQty = objNode.selectSingleNode("quantity").Text
    mQty = objNode.selectSingleNode("size").Text



' get the modifiers for that node
Set objNodeList2 = objNode.selectNodes(".//modifier")
For Each objNode2 In objNodeList2

    mName = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("name").Text
    mPrice = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("price").Text
    mQty = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("quantity").Text

Next objNode2
Next
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I tried it and it didn't work at first, but I made a change and it works great now! Here is the updated version:        For Each objNode In objNodeList
              
                        mName = objNode2.selectSingleNode("name").Text
                        mPrice = objNode2.selectSingleNode("price").Text
                        mQty = objNode2.selectSingleNode("quantity").Text
                    
                    Next objNode2
        Next